# Get rid of arrow button on SearchView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using a search view in my Android App and I am trying to get rid of the blue underline. I managed to get rid of the blue underline that appears under the text using:

```
int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
View searchPlateView = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
if (searchPlateView != null) {
    searchPlateView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

However there is an arrow button to the right of the text within the searchview that still has the blue underline. I either want to get rid of this arrow or get rid of the underline.

Here is a screenshot of what the searchview looks like: http://tinypic.com/r/fvzl74/8

Comment: Could you post a screenshot somewhere and link to it, illustrating what you are referring to?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the searchview: http://tinypic.com/r/fvzl74/8
(As you can see the blue line still remains under the arrow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of it using .setSubmitButtonEnabled(false)